# How do I provide missing declarations in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

How do I provide additional declaration to static class functions in TypeScript? For example, I am using Chrome Canary with the experimental `Object.observe()` JavaScript function. In order to use it (without resorting to an any cast), I want to declare the `Object.observe` function. How do I do this?

```
declare ?; // What goes here?

var x = {};
Object.observe( x, ( update : any ) => { console.log("Hello"); } ); // Declaration needed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create an interface:

```
interface Object {
  observe(beingObserved: any, callback: (update: any) => any) : void;
}
```

Then just reference that interface in your `.ts` file.  As of `0.8.1.1`, Intellisense is kind of flaky, but it works and will enforce the contract during compile.

It will also highlight the places where you use `Object.observe` with `Ambiguous call expression - could not choose overload`, but it will compile nonetheless.